# Reverse the order of first 3 words of input line using Pattern matching

Tags: perl

I have a question in Perl:
Reverse the order of the first three words of each input line using the substitution operator. Leave the spacing unchanged, and print each resulting line.

How can I solve this?Any idea?Thanks in advance.

Comment: A homework question from here? [Problems and Solutions](http://marilyn.indstate.edu/~ping/yang/compSci/perl/problems.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$line =~ s/^(\s*)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)/$1$6$3$4$5$2/;
```

Not posting full code cus it seems to be homework or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Though awk is not tagged .Probably you would like to know about the awk solution for this:

```
awk '{x=$3" "$2" "$1;$3=$2=$1=""; print x,$0}' your_file
```